# Add image in media element in typo3

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I am stuck with a problem.
I added a video using typo3 TCA media.
Now i want to add thumbnail image to the video.
I extended sys_file_reference, added image inside that video.
I do not know how to render it,
following is my typoscript

```
        dataProcessing.1676624357 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
    dataProcessing.1676624357 {
        if.isTrue.field = media
        references.fieldName = media
        references.table = tt_content
        sorting = sorting_foreign
        as = media
    
        dataProcessing {
            115511551155 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
            115511551155 {
                references.fieldName = thumbnail_image
                references.table = sys_file_reference
            }
        }
    }
```